# MVC Routing with Typescript via Url.Action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, typescript, asp.net-mvc-routing, url-routing

In all of my views, I use strong MVC routes at all times. So instead of doing this:

```
<a href="/Pages/About">Click here</a>
```

I do this:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("About", "Page")">Click here</a>
```

I much prefer this method, because that way if I ever change the route, the link remains connected. If I were to use the first method and I change the routing for "/Pages/About" to "/AboutPage", the first link will break, whereas the second will automatically map.

**Now on to the problem:**

I am very new to TypeScript, and I want to use it to make AJAX requests to my MVC controllers. Currently I can't see a way to embed a link to a controller action using Url.Action in a TypeScript file. Are there any methods to create a strong link when using TypeScript? I don't want to use a string unless I absolutely must.

Basically I want to avoid this:

```
$.ajax({
        url: '/Page/AboutJson',
        cache: false,
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json'
    });
```

And do this (or very similar) instead:

```
$.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("AboutJson", "Page")',
        cache: false,
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json'
    });
```

Comment: use html5 data attributes

Comment: @EhsanSajjad could you elaborate please? How could I use them in the above example?

Comment: you would be calling the ajax call on some html element event right? can you show that html and type script code

Comment: @EhsanSajjad I'm using it with KnockoutJS, so the URLs are not directly bound to a HTML element.

Comment: i think you can use knockout bnding for that as well